# Net48 to net60 migration: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=6.0.0.0...'

Tags: c#, nuget, migration, nuget-package, .net-6.0

I am migrating my application from net48 to net60. During the migration, I have to update my custom NuGet package to support net60 and add it to my application, but during the build, I am getting an error:

> WcfWrapperGenerator.targets(36, 5): Could not load file or assembly
> 'System.Runtime, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The
> system cannot find the file specified.

actual place where the error (line 36):

```
<GenerateWrappers ContractsAssemblies="@(_source)"
                  ContractsReferences="@(_references)"
                  OutputNamespace="$(GenWithNamespace)"
                  OutputPath="$(GenWrapperFilesPath)">
```

How can I fix it?

Also, I see an error, when trying to get code analysis:

```
Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.Query.QueryExecutionException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices.CSharp.ProjectSystemShim.EntryPointFinder.FindEntryPoints(INamespaceSymbol symbol)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.Properties.StartupObjectsEnumGenerator.<GetListedValuesAsync>d__8.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.PropertyPages.PageDynamicEnumProperty.<CreateAdmissibleValuesAsync>d__6.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Query.SupportedValueDataProducer.<CreateSupportedValuesAsync>d__1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Query.QueryDataFromProviderStateProducerBase`1.<SendRequestAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.Query.QueryExecution.QuerySubscription`1.<RunQueryOnceAsync>d__9.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.Query.QueryExecution.QuerySubscription`1.<>c__DisplayClass8_0.<<Start>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Implementation.PropertyPages.Designer.ProjectPropertyDataAccess.Observer.<InitializeAsync>d__10.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Implementation.PropertyPages.Designer.ProjectPropertyDataAccess.Observer.<CreateAsync>d__9.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Implementation.PropertyPages.Designer.ProjectPropertiesEditor.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<<-ctor>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Implementation.PropertyPages.Designer.AsyncLoadContent.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<<Initialize>b__0>d.MoveNext()
```

Comment: Did you try to delete all `bin` and `obj` folders when Visual Studio is closed? I had this issue a lot of times during migration

Comment: @mu88 yes, I did, but I will try one more time. Also, do you know does the installation order of Visual Studio make sense? I have installed 2022 and after 2017. Can it break something?

Comment: No that shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Unexpectedly, it was a problem.